# Checking if a text file has all entries and is formatted correctly

Tags: awk, csv, csv-simple

I have a file that is like this

```
0001;4;5;30;33;41;52
0002;9;37;39;41;43;49
0003;10;11;29;30;36;47
0004;1;5;6;27;42;59
0005;1;2;6;16;19;46
0006;7;13;19;22;40;47
0007;3;5;20;21;38;56
... etc
```

The first number is a counter and the following six are 1 or 2 digit numbers.

The file has thousands of lines like this. It starts at 1 and goes to 9999.

is there a way to check if there is a line missing? I mean if all numbers are present from the one at the first line to the one of the last line?

I mean like this:

```
0001;4;5;30;33;41;52      // first line
0002;9;37;39;41;43;49
0003;10;11;29;30;36;47
...
9999;3;4;8;12;55;88       // last line
```

is there any line missing between 0001 and 9999?

Suppose this:

```
0001;4;5;30;33;41;52     
0002;9;37;39;41;43;49
0003;10;11;29;30;36;47
0004;1;5;6;27;42;59
0006;7;13;19;22;40;47
```

see? 0005 is missing.

As a bonus, it would be nice to check if all seven numbers are delimited by `;` and not any other character.

Thanks

Comment: *is there a way to check if there is a line missing?* - elaborate the final result. Would it be enough to find the 1st missed line OR it should print the numbers of ALL missed lines?

Comment: if it prints the first like it is ok, because I can fix it and run the command again, finding the next problem and so one.

Comment: post the approximate expected output for both conditions

Comment: output? Suppose the command is checking for the presence of lines with number 1, 2, 3, 4... error... 4 is missing. The output can be only the line number

Comment: I have added more info at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`AWK`** solution (assuming your *if it prints the first like it is ok*):

Sample file `input.csv`:

```
0001;4;5;30;33;41;52
0002;9;37;39;41;43;49
0003;10;11;29;30;36;47
0005;1;2;6;16;19;46
0006;7;13;19;22;40;47
0007;3;5;20;21;38;56
0008;1;5,6;27;42;59
0009;10;1;6;27;42;59
```

---

for condition *to check if there is a line missing*:

```
awk -F';' 'NR!=int($1){ printf "%04d is missing\n",NR; exit }' input.csv
```

The output:

```
0004 is missing
```

---

for condition *to check if all **seven** numbers are delimited by `;`*:

```
awk -F';' 'NF!=7{printf "Incorrect number of fields: %d on record %d\n",NF,NR; exit}' input.csv
```

The output:

```
Incorrect number of fields: 6 on record 7
```

Comment: SIMPLY BRILLIANT! YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: if you want another easy points, try [this other question of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408368/changing-the-line-endings-of-a-unix-file-to-windows-m-not-working)  

Comment: @SpaceDog there's no way with Roman :D:D genius is less for him :D:D:D:D

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Greetings Ukraine PYTHON GENIUS LOL

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, please, I'm not a genius, you are too kind )

Comment: You could use `NR` or `FNR` instead of keeping the `c` counter

Comment: @glennjackman, yes, that would be even simpler

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, to find any line with an unwanted character:

```
grep '[^0-9;]' filename
```

which will output any line in the file that contains a character that is not a number or a semicolon. Use `grep -n` to find the line number of these offending lines.