# Changing the line endings of a unix file to windows ^M not working

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that is using unix notation for line endings and another one that is using Windows notation.

When I `vi` the unix file, I see nothing at the line ending. When I `vi` the windows file I see `^M` in blue

[image]

The problem is that from the middle down, the lines contain no `^M`in blue (??).

I am trying to convert the whole file to have `^M` on all lines.

I have tried a lot of commands, but this one in particular

```
sed -e 's/$/^M/' < input.txt > output.txt
```

add "^M" as two characters, not as `Command-M` and it does that also on the lines that already have the correct `^M` character...

I have also tried

```
sed -e 's/\r/^M/' < input.txt > output.txt
```

and

```
sed -e 's/\n/^M/' < input.txt > output.txt
```

without success...

issuing a `cat -e input.txt` I see this on the ^M correct lines:

```
1895;2;3;5;10;14;34^M$
1896;3;6;14;15;21;25^M$
1897;9;22;25;47;52;58^M$
1898;12;34;45;53;55;58^M$
```

and this on the incorrect ones

```
1899;20;23;35;36;44;48$
1900;8;11;27;28;43;46$
1901;11;12;26;30;37;53$
1902;02;07;09;18;21;25$
1903;09;10;15;28;43;45$
```

How do I get all lines with command-m ?

Comment: suggestion: add output of `cat -A input.txt` to question instead of `vi` image... use `\r` to add carriage return... might depend on sed version, so add that info as well

Comment: What system are you running? I thought I saw Macs mentioned, but I can't see it now?

Comment: `dos2unix`, no?

Comment: @Vlastimil exacly what I were thinking. I assume that OP will need to convert more files in the future, so it's totally worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Perl, using that is the easiest way to sidestep different versions of `sed` etc.

```
perl -pe 's/\r?$/\r/' < infile > outfile
```

Or in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\r?$/\r/' infile
```

That will add a carriage return to the end of all lines, except the ones that already have one. (Or actually, replace zero or one CR:s with one CR.)

---

Test:

```
$ cat -e infile
with cr^M$
no cr$
still no cr$

$ perl -pe 's/\r?$/\r/' < infile |cat -e
with cr^M$
no cr^M$
still no cr^M$

$ perl --version
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
[...]
```

---

I think I saw a mention of macOS somewhere. If that's what you're using, the issue there is that the `sed` that comes with it doesn't support half the things GNU sed supports. The one on my Mac doesn't seem to support `\r` or `\xHH`...

But you can stick a literal carriage return on the command line:

```
sed -Ee 's/^M?$/^M/' < infile > outfile
```

The `^M` there is not the two characters `^` and `M`, but the single carriage return, which the shell (I suppose you'll have Bash) displays as `^M`. You need to enter the character with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd>

Or, alternatively, have the shell interpret the `\r` for you:

```
sed -Ee $'s/\r?$/\r/' < infile > outfile
```

(The `$'...'` syntax is supported by almost all shells, even though it's not standard (as far as I understand))

Comment: the first one is doing the opposite of what I want. It is removing all `^M`. What I want is to replace the line ends that are not `^M` with `^M`

Comment: oh, so mac sed doesn't support `\xHH` too? I thought it was posix thing..

Comment: sorry but none of your commands are working for me. The only one that is minimally working is this: `perl -pe 's/\r?$/\r\n/' < input.txt > output.txt`. This command is correctly adding `^M` to lines without it, but it is also adding a new line after the `^M`... so the output file contains a blank line between the  but this one is adding a new blank line between every line that came from the input file

Comment: @Sundeep, frankly, I've no idea what parts of `sed` are standard and what aren't... I'm just sitting here with a Mac, and the `sed` doesn't seem to support those, so...

Comment: @Sundeep - I don't know that but all I know is that your commands are removing () all my beautiful `^M`...

Comment: @SpaceDog, You added an extra `\n` there, so sure, then it adds another newline.

Comment: @SpaceDog okay lets try an experiment... 1) `seq 5 > ip.txt` 2) `perl -i -pe 's/$/\r/ if $.%2==0' ip.txt` 3) `perl -pe 's/\r?\n/\r\n/' ip.txt | cat -e` ... tell us what you get

Comment: ok, `cat -e` apparently shows that all lines are correct but, for some reason `vi` is not showing those characters as blue `^M`...

Comment: @SpaceDog, right, vim is smart enough to realize that the file has windows/DOS line endings, so it hides them from you. When I start it on a file with CRLF line ends, it shows e.g. `"outfile" [dos] 3L, 29C`, hinting at that.

Answer (score 0):

[unix2dos](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos) should work for you in this case. However, it seems that you're using macOS, which has no repository for that program, I'd suggest `sed -e 's/\n/\r\n/' < input.txt > output.txt` which is only a bit less convenient.

Comment: not working. File continues exactly as it is.

Comment: sed will remove `\n` from each line as it processes it and adds it back while printing, so you cannot match `\n` like mentioned here

Comment: could you please post the output of `python -c "with open('input.txt') as f: print(repr(f.readline()))"` for us to see?

Comment: it just printed the first line and the line endings of that line is `\r\n`... `vi` shows this line with a blue `^M`